# Classic ASP integration with the Tumblr API

Tags: api, asp-classic, tumblr

Trying to integrate Classic ASP with the Tumblr API. I want to automate the The Tumblr write API along with posts from the Classic ASP website. The Tumblr API is located here: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api.

This is the write  PHP example for the Tumblr API.

```php
// Authorization info  
$tumblr_email    = 'info@davidville.com';  
$tumblr_password = 'secret';  

// Data for new record  
$post_type  = 'regular';  
$post_title = 'The post title';  
$post_body  = 'This is the body of the post.';  

// Prepare POST request  
$request_data = http_build_query(  
    array(  
        'email'     => $tumblr_email,  
        'password'  => $tumblr_password,  
        'type'      => $post_type,  
        'title'     => $post_title,  
        'body'      => $post_body,  
        'generator' => 'API example'  
    )  
);  

// Send the POST request (with cURL)  
$c = curl_init('http://www.tumblr.com/api/write');  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_data);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$result = curl_exec($c);  
$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
curl_close($c);  

// Check for success  
if ($status == 201) {  
    echo "Success! The new post ID is $result.\n";  
} else if ($status == 403) {  
    echo 'Bad email or password';  
} else {  
    echo "Error: $result\n";  
}
```

I'm trying a translation into ASP. I need to know how to get the status back from the page. Even a hint to start with would be great. A solution, even better. I've gotten this far with Classic ASP and Microsoft XMLHttpObject:

```vb
' Authorization info  
tumblr_email    = "info@davidville.com"  
tumblr_password = "secret"  

' Data for new record  
post_type  = "regular"  
post_title = "The post title"  
post_body  = "This is the body of the post."  

' Prepare POST request  
request_data = "email=" tumblr_email & "&" &  
request_data = request_data & "password=" & tumblr_password & "&" &  
request_data = request_data & "type=" & post_type & "&" &  
request_data = request_data & "title=" & post_title & "&" &  
request_data = request_data & "body=" & post_body & "&" &  
request_data = request_data & "generator=Your Generator Name"  

request_data = server.urlencode(request_data)  

Dim objHttp, strQuery  
strQuery = “http://www.tumblr.com/api/write”  
set objHttp = Server.CreateObject(“Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP”)  
objHttp.open “GET”, strQuery, false  
objHttp.send  
Response.Write objHttp.ResponseText  
Set objHttp = Nothing
```

Here's the correct code, after trial and error, for a regular post to Tumblr using Classic ASP. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/69820/oracle-certified-professional for the help.

```vb
' Authorization info  
tumblr_email = "your_registered_email"  
tumblr_password = "your_tumblr_password"  

' Data for new record  
post_type = "regular"  
post_title = "The post title"  
post_body = "This is the body of the post."  

' Prepare POST request  
request_data = "email=" & tumblr_email & "&"  
request_data = request_data & "password=" & tumblr_password & "&"  
request_data = request_data & "type=" & post_type & "&"  
request_data = request_data & "title=" & server.urlencode(post_title) & "&"  
request_data = request_data & "body=" & server.urlencode(post_body)  

set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")  
http.open "POST", "http://www.tumblr.com/api/write", false  
http.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  
http.setRequestHeader "Content-length", len(content)  
http.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"  
http.send request_data  
Response.Write http.responseText
```

I'll be adding other examples for Tumblr posts (photos, quotes, etc.) on http://www.genxts.com in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a POST request via classic ASP, all you need to do is use the `MSXML2` library (as you would do in IE Ajax):

build your request data as a url string the same way as you buid parameters for a GET. Make sure it's urlencoded

```
dim request_data: request_data = "key1=value1&key2=value2"
```

create the request object and connect to the url via post. the 3rd parameter determines whether the call is synchronous or not. presumably you need the server version of the object, instead of the standard `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` object

```
dim http: set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
http.open "POST", "http://www.tumblr.com/api/write", false
```

set any http request headers you need

```
http.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "..."
```

add your request data to the request

```
http.send request_data
```

you can then access the response via

```
dim text: text = http.responseText
```

or

```
dim xml: set xml = http.responseXML
```

depending on the type of data you're returning. Here's a handy link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754586(v=VS.85).aspx

---

ok, I managed to get this to work

```
dim http: set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

dim email: email = "email@example.com"
dim password: password = "*password"
dim content: content = content & "type=regular"
content = content & "&body=this is a test"

content = content & "&email=" & email
content = content & "&password=" & password



http.open "POST", "http://www.tumblr.com/api/write", false
http.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.setRequestHeader "Content-length", len(content)
http.setRequestHeader "Connection", "close"

http.send content
Response.Write http.responseText
```

it seems it didn't like the URL encoding. I tried just encoding the other content that wasn't the email & password

```
content = Server.URLEncode(content)
content = content & "&email=" & email
content = content & "&password=" & password
```

but I got a "post must not be empty" message

Comment: What content-type should I use ?I guess I'm getting close because I'm getting "Authorization Failed" as a text response. Anyway to translate this page (http://efreedom.com/Question/1-2326071/Sending-POST-Request-Cocoa-Tumblr) into the Classic ASP example above. Since the Tumblr API doesn't give actual specific error messages, this is just trial and error at this point.

Comment: you were almost there. i had to check the api documentation. regular posts need a title and body. also, if you don't server.urlencode the email, password and type, just everything else, it works. thanks for the help good sir.